# .gitignore. Как такое может быть?

Tags: git

Как такое может быть что сам файл .gitignore стал отслеживаться и появляться в ответе от команды git status -s (модифицирован -М) ?

Я в нем просто внутри добавил запись безобидную ( *.txt ) и все . Такие дела .

Comment: Что же здесь не так? Всё работает как нужно. Ну, добавили запись в `.gitignore`, как, например, это получить Вашим коллегам?

Comment: Ясно . Логично.  Получается мне нужно добавить это все в индекс и затем скомитить и он пропадет . Просто сбило  с толку  что  то  что создано для игнора само  повело себя наоборот )

Answer (score 1):

Файл `.gitignore` - это такой же файл, и он точно так же хранится в гите как и любой другой неигнорируемый файл.

Если вы не желаете делиться своими списками игнорирования с коллегами - можете использовать фaйл `.git/info/exclude`, но обычно лучше поделиться.

Comment: Ага я понял . Этот  .gitignore вернее то что то нем - его содержимое , просто не дает  оповещение при разынх своих  изменениях но все же  благополучно входить снимок ну  и так далее . А то что  Вы говроите это еще строже - исключается из снимка. Спасибо за комментарий - разобрался более менее.

Comment: @qq нет, файлы работают одинаково, просто один из них сам хранится в гите, а второй нет

Comment: *хранится в гите как и любой другой **неигнорируемый** файл* — история игнорируемого файла вполне может присутствовать в хранилище. про это регулярно вопросы задают. как-то по-другому надо. может, «отслеживаемый»?